# Variable accesible desde toda la app

Tags: java, android

Hay alguna forma de tener una variable y que esta pueda ser accesible desde toda la app ? No solo desde el activity en el que me encuentre.

Comment: Al final opte por definir una clase "`global`" y declarar todo como estático sin inicializar e ir rellenando conforme extraigo datos de la DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Puedes crear una clase publica**, de hecho es común tener esto en los proyectos y **las variables a acceder deben ser definidas como estáticas**:

```
public class GlobalInfo {

    public static final String PREFS_CONFIG = "Breaking_News";
    public static final String PREFS_SYSTEM = "GR_System";

    public static final int MINUTE_MILISECONDS = 60000;
    public static final int IDPUB = 2001;

    ...
    ...
    ...   


}
```

Desde otra clase podrás acceder a estos valores, por ejemplo:

```
 Long period = GlobalInfo.MINUTE_MILISECONDS;
 String nombreConfiguracion = GlobalInfo.PREFS_CONFIG;
```

---

**Otra forma es que tu clase que contendrá la variable "global", extienda de [**Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application)**:**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private String valorInicial = "Breaking_News";

    public String getValorInicial() {
        return valorInicial;
    }

    public void setValorInicial(String valorInicial) {
        this.valorInicial = valorInicial;
    }
}
```

Obviamente esta clase debe ser definida en nuestro archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
   android:name=".MyApplication"

   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label=""@string/app_name">
```

y de esta forma podrás acceder a la variable:

```
String valor = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getValorInicial();
```

Answer (score 1):

tienes que crear una clase con acceso público y definir los atributos como variable estática, te adjunto un ejemplo:

```java
public class Globales {
    public static String nombres = "Juan";
    public static String apellidos = "Perez";
}
```

Posteriormente puedes llamarlo desde un activity, fragment, etc.

```java
// Imprimir valores de inicio
Log.d("SO", Globales.nombres);
Log.d("SO", Globales.apellidos);

// Podemos modificar su valor
Globales.nombres = "Juan 2";
Globales.apellidos = "Perez 2";


// Imprimir valores modificados
Log.d("SO", Globales.nombres);
Log.d("SO", Globales.apellidos);
```